# Angular change URL on page load

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a schedule for a convention and would like to have the URL change during the convention time. If the user loads the page on Saturday of the con, the URL should change to [URL]?day=saturday.(The URL will also change when the user clicks to view different day)

I'm running into an issue on page load only, where the history.replaceState is causing

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

So I came across a forum that says to use something like

```
$location.path('/').search('day='+day).replace();
```

But it comes out as

```
/#/?day=saturday
```

I don't want the /# in the URL. So I found forums explaining to use $locationProvider.

I even added in the

```
app.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

And it still says $locationProvider is not defined. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if this is even the right direction to be going in. I just want to change the ?day=day_here when the page loads and when the user clicks to change the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the route change on click when routing and replace the url. For the error use and your syntax seems to be right

```
.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
})
```

But if you want to persist the url change you will have to do the changes to url in the routeChange

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
   //... you could trigger something here like replacing the actual url ...
   //$location.path('/').search('day='+day).replace();
 });
})
```

Alternatively you can also look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router as an alternative and do the changes to $location.url().replace() in onEnter or resolve options of state definition https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

If you want to use ngRouter and still getting the error a plunkr code for demo will surely help debug better.

Comment: This works for the most part. But when the user clicks on the name of the event, it doesn't navigate away to the event page like it used to. It just changes the URL.

Comment: Is name of the event a page/route in your application? If so what is the error you are getting. There must be a blocking script that is blocking the page route. Can you put the code for the routeChangeStart that you are using? Preferably a simple plnkr should be good.